# Error occurred when opening my ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

The error is:

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio --------------------------
>
> The following error occurred attempting to run the project model server process (1.0.0-preview3-004056).
>
> Unable to start the process. Found dotnet SDK, but did not find
>   dotnet.dll at [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview3-004056\dotnet.dll]

I removed that version because it wasn't the version i wanted. Now I try installing the latest version, even tried to install an older version but still get this error when opening the project. When I run dotnetcore --version i get this:

> C:\Windows\system32>dotnet --version
>
> Found dotnet SDK, but did not find dotnet.dll at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.
>   0.0-preview3-004056\dotnet.dll]

How do I tell dotnet to set a specific version that is already installed?

Update: I removed VS 2017 RC and re-install VS 2015 Update 3 but that didn't work. I ended up having to add a global.json and specify the version that I wanted to use.

```
  "sdk": {
"version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"}
```

That worked but I had to install some packages manually.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Similar problem here. Installed VS 2017 RC on top of VS 2015 Update 3 which somehow messed up v1.0.0-preview3-004056. Pointing explicitly to right version in global.json didn't fix it for me.

Comment: Exactly i forgot to mentioned that I installed VS 2017 RC on top of VS 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Actually it looks like as project model server process ahould be an extension to .net providing intellisense and some other project stuff to VS. For some reason that extension gets removed when installing VS2017 RC, which leads to mentioned error. Uninstalling both versions of VS and reinstalling VS2015 Update3 fixed it for me. No more side by side installation of 2015 and 2017 for me anymore tho...

Comment: Blew up for me, too. Opened just fine for me yesterday. Installed VS 2017 RC today and it blows up exactly as described above. When will I learn not to listen to the hype from Connect() event.. sigh..

Comment: Update: Just uninstalled VS 2017 RC. My . ASP.NET Core 1.0 web app now opens just fine now.  I didn't have to reinstall VS 2015 Update 3.